# difficulty understanding MPI scatter and gather in C

Tags: c, mpi

I am trying to learn to use MPI. Below is my simple program to test MPI scatter and gather. I don't understand how it works and why it produces the result

```
1 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

instead of expected

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

The documentation and all the examples I can find are too complicated/poorly worded for me to understand. I just want to scatter an array across 3 processes and add one to each value in each process. Alternatively I would be happy to see how a 2D array was sent row by row to each process and each row was processed simply.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int rank; // my process ID
    int size = 3; // number of processes/nodes
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); // start MPI
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size); // initialize MPI
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    unsigned char inData[12]; // data returned after being "processed"
    unsigned char outData[12]; // buffer for receiving data
    unsigned long datasize = 12; // size of data to process
    unsigned char testData[12]; // data to be processed

    if (rank == 0) {
        // initialize data
        for (int i = 0; i < datasize; i++) {
            testData[i] = i;
            outData[i] = 0;
            inData[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    // scatter the data to the processes
    // I am not clear about the numbers sent in and out
    MPI_Scatter(&testData, 12, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, &outData, 
        12, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // process data
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { outData[i] = outData[i] + 1; }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // gather processed data
    MPI_Gather(&outData, 12, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, &inData, 
        12, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    //print processed data from root 
    if (rank == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            printf("\n%d", inData[i]);
        }

        MPI_Finalize();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with MPI but... Isn't the `MPI_Scatter` being executed by all the processes?

Comment: You should not use `count=12` in the collective operations. Also, all ranks must call `MPI_Finalize()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though your main error is using `12` instead of `4`, let's do it step-by-step.

```
// int size = 3; // number of processes/nodes
int size;
...
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size); // initialize MPI
assert(size == 3);
```

There is no point in setting `size` to `3`. This value will be overwritten by `MPI_Comm_size` with the actual number of processes. This number is determined by how you run your MPI application (e.g. `mpirun -np 3`).

```
//unsigned char outData[12]; // buffer for receiving data
unsigned char outData[4];
```

We have 12 elements and 3 processes, 4 elements per processes. So, 4 elements are enough for `outData`.

```
outData[i] = 0;
inData[i] = 0;
```

There is no point in zeroing these buffers, they will be overwritten.

```
// scatter the data to the processes
// I am not clear about the numbers sent in and out
MPI_Scatter(&testData, 4 /*12*/, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, &outData,
    4 /*12*/, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

We have 4 elements per processes, so the number should be 4, not 12.

```
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

You don't need barriers here.

```
MPI_Gather(&outData, 4 /*12*/, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, &inData, 
    4 /*12*/, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Same story, `4` instead of `12`.

```
MPI_Finalize();
```

This should be called by all processes.

Comment: the `assert()` is only here to abort if there are not 3 MPI tasks (since `4` is hardcoded, the program will fail if ran with a different number of tasks). `MPI_Scatter()` nor `MPI_Barrier()` are barriers. For example, in a `MPI_Scatter()`, the root rank might return before non root rank even enter `MPI_Scatter()`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, that's true, corrected the answer. The point was that `MPI_Barrier()` are not needed here.